# Swipe-out in Backbonejs without jQuery

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I have problem with swipe-out function like [this](http://ankane.github.io/swipeout/demo.html) in my backbone app. When I trying add hammer.js to HEAD there is error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'addEventListener'  hammer.min.js:7
```

Do you know other javascript than hammer.js, without dependency on jquery working properly in backbone?

My HEAD

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Backbone App</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/require/require.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/utils.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/hammer/swipeout.js"></script>
</head>
```

My main.js

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'jquery': 'libs/jquery/jquery.min',
    'underscore': 'libs/lodash/lodash.min',
    'backbone': 'libs/backbone/backbone.min',
    'templates': '../templates',
    'hammer': 'libs/hammer/hammer.min'
  },
    shim : {

    }
});
require(['jquery'], function($) {
    return {};
});

require([
  // Load our app module and pass it to our definition function
  'app'

], function(App){
  // The "app" dependency is passed in as "App"
  // Again, the other dependencies passed in are not "AMD" therefore don't pass a parameter to this function
  App.initialize();
});
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: i think that the problem could be in requirejs or some library not loaded, an you show your require main file?

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri Minoccheri I already add hammerjs to main.js but now I have different error message. (I checked, hammer.js is loaded...)

Comment: @Makromat I've created a sample Backbone webapp using Hammer and SwipeOut and shared the details in my answer below. Please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a sample web application using SwipeOut, Hammer, Jquery and Backbone. I've committed the code to [github repository](https://github.com/manishcm/swipeout-backbone). Had to change Swipeout to provide AMD version of it, hence use this [swipeout.js](https://github.com/manishcm/swipeout-backbone/blob/master/js/lib/swipeout.js) file.

Instead of loading hammer and swipeout from index.html, load them asynchronously from any of the javascript files. 
Make following changes:

1. Remove the swipeout script tag from index.html
2. Update main.js as shown below. Since swipe.js, Backbone, underscore and jquery are non AMD files, you need to define the shim configuration. Note that Hammer is a AMD module, so shim configuration is not required for it. For demonstration purpose, I'm loading the hammer and swipeout files in app module.

> ```
> require.config({
>   paths: {
>     'jquery': 'libs/jquery/jquery.min',
>     'underscore': 'libs/lodash/lodash.min',
>     'backbone': 'libs/backbone/backbone.min',
>     'templates': '../templates',
>     'hammer': 'libs/hammer/hammer.min',
>     'swipeout': 'libs/hammer/swipeout'
>   },
>    shim : {
>     'backbone': {
>         deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
>         exports: 'Backbone'
>     },
>     'underscore': {
>         exports: '_'
>     },
>     'jquery': {
>         exports: '$'
>     },
>     'swipeout': {
>        exports: 'SwipeOut'
>     }
>   }
> });
>
> require([
>   // Load our app module and pass it to our definition function
>   'app',
>   'hammer',
>   'swipeout',
>   'jquery'
>
> ], function(App,Hammer,Swipeout, $){
>   // The "app" dependency is passed in as "App"
>   // Again, the other dependencies passed in are not "AMD" therefore don't pass a parameter to this function
>   App.initialize();
> });
> ```

Let me know if it solves the issue.